# Post.count to_sql in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

I have a model name Post. When I try to run
Post.count I get a result without a problem.
However, I suspect that Ruby is used to count the number of posts returned.

Instead, I'd like to use SQL to count the number of posts, as it is much faster.

The only way I have found to achieve this using Arel is `Post.select("COUNT(id)")`.
Is there no way to run a `count` command without explicitly calling select on the model?
Thanks!

Comment: Ruby is not used to count the number of posts, the `count` method is this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want? :

```
Post.where(your_sql).count
```

Read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 13):

Post.count should generate the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"
```

Edit:  You can see the queries generated by looking at your development.log file.